# Check if a string is empty or only whitespace characters in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, whitespace

How do I check if a string is empty or all whitespace characters in racket? [the example on their site](https://docs.racket-lang.org/heresy/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._heresy%2Fmain..rkt%29._empty%7E24%7E3f%29%29) (`string$?`) doesn't work

Comment: That documentation is for "The Heresy Programming Language", not Racket...

Comment: @Óscar López oh, but how would i do it then?

Comment: @Óscar López doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regexp-match-exact?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-match-exact%7E3f%29%29) with this regex: `#px"\\s*"`, which matches whitespace character zero or more times:

```
> (regexp-match-exact? #px"\\s*" "a")
#f
> (regexp-match-exact? #px"\\s*" "")
#t
> (regexp-match-exact? #px"\\s*" "    ")
#t
> (regexp-match-exact? #px"\\s*" "
")
#t
```

`non-empty-string?` has different results for empty string and string with whitespace characters:

```
> (non-empty-string? "  ")
#t
> (non-empty-string? "")
#f
```

Comment: Best solution :) works even with racket/base and works with only empty string, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using some hairy regexp (there's a famous quote about regexps ...) you might consider just expressing what you want: a string all of whose characters are whitespace:

```
(define (string-whitespace? s)
  (for/and ([c (in-string s)])
    (char-whitespace? c)))
```

Note that the empty string satisfies this trivially.  But the empty string is also a string *none* of whose characters are white, so probably:

```
(define (string-not-whitespace? s)
  (or (string=? s "")
      (not (string-whitespace? s))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd trim the string first:

```
> (non-empty-string? "         ")
#t
> (non-empty-string?  (string-trim "         "))
#f
> (non-empty-string?  (string-trim "
"))
#f
```

string-trim is not in racket/base, unlike regexp-match-exact? , but the less regex I see, the better I feel, so I'd rather let it worry about what the correct regex to remove spaces is.